# Laravel - Eloquent - Filter based on latest HasMany relation

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this two models, Leads and Status.

```
class Lead extends Model
{
    public function statuses() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\LeadStatus', 'lead_id', 'id')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }

    public function activeStatus() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\LeadStatus', 'lead_id', 'id')
            ->latest();
    }


}

class LeadStatus extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['status', 'lead_id'];
}
```

This works fine, now I'm trying to get all Leads based on the 'status' of the last LeadStatus.

I've tried a few combinations with no success.

```
if ($search['status']) {
            $builder = $builder
                ->whereHas('statuses', function($q) use ($search){
                    $q = $q->latest()->limit(1);
                    $q->where('status', $search['status']);
                });
        }



 if ($search['status']) {
            $builder = $builder
                ->whereHas('status', function($q) use ($search){
                    $q = $q->latest()->Where('status', $search['status']);
                });
        }
```

Has anybody done this with Eloquent? Do I need to write some raw SQL queries?

EDIT 1: I'll try to explain again :D

In my database, the status of a lead is not a 1 to 1 relation. That is because I want to have a historic list of all the statuses which a Lead has had.

That means that when a Lead is created, the first LeadStatus is created with the status of 'new' and the current date.

If a salesman comes in, he can change the status of the lead, but this DOES NOT update the previous LeadStatus, instead it creates a new related LeadStatus with the current date and status of 'open'.

This way I can see that a Lead was created on 05/05/2018 and that it changed to the status 'open' on 07/05/2018.

Now I'm trying to write a query using eloquent, which only takes in count the LATEST status related to a Lead.

In the previous example, if I filter by Lead with status 'new', this Lead should not appear as it has a status of 'open' by now.

Hope this helps

Comment: so you want to get the Lead by status so to say?For instance to get all Leads with the status 1

Comment: Exactly, but only by the latest status of the Lead.

That means that if the lead has a related status of open from 2 weeks ago and another status that is closed 1 week ago. It should be returned only if I filter for closed Leads

Comment: Still did not understand it 100% could you explain again :)

Comment: Added some lines, hope it's clearer now

Comment: So you filter the Leads through the status and another property? Couldn't you use the `->latest()` helper method of laravel in addition to the query to accomplish this?:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```php
Lead::select('leads.*')
    ->join('lead_statuses', 'leads.id', 'lead_statuses.lead_id')
    ->where('lead_statuses.status', $search['status'])
    ->where('created_at', function($query) {
        $query->selectRaw('max(created_at)')
            ->from('lead_statuses')
            ->whereColumn('lead_id', 'leads.id');
    })->get();
```

A solution using the primary key (by Borjante):

```
    $builder->where('lead_statuses.id', function($query) {
        $query->select('id')
            ->from('lead_statuses')
            ->whereColumn('lead_id', 'leads.id')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->limit(1);
    });
```

Comment: Good morning Sir, works great. I'll give it some thoughts because I'm not in love with filtering by created at

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and posted [my solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115064/laravel-wherehas-checking-latest-record-of-a-relationship-without-checking-oth/54344264#54344264) but I think it's worth re-posting as it improves on the re-usability. It's the same idea as the accepted answer but avoids using joins, which can cause issues if you want to eager load relations or use it in a scope.

The first step involves adding a macro to the query `Builder` in the `AppServiceProvider`.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;

Builder::macro('whereLatestRelation', function ($table, $parentRelatedColumn) 
{
    return $this->where($table . '.id', function ($sub) use ($table, $parentRelatedColumn) {
        $sub->select('id')
            ->from($table . ' AS other')
            ->whereColumn('other.' . $parentRelatedColumn, $table . '.' . $parentRelatedColumn)
            ->latest()
            ->take(1);
    });
});
```

This basically makes the sub-query part of the accepted answer more generic, allowing you to specify the join table and the column they join on. It also uses the `latest()` function to avoid referencing the `created_at` column directly. It assumes the other column is an 'id' column, so it can be improved further. To use this you'd then be able to do:

```
$status = $search['status'];
Lead::whereHas('statuses', function ($q) use ($status) {
    $q->where('status', $userId)
        ->whereLatestRelation((new LeadStatus)->getTable(), 'lead_id');
});
```

It's the same logic as the accepted answer, but a bit easier to re-use. It will, however, be a little slower, but that should be worth the re-usability.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you need / want to get all Leads with a specific status.

So you probably should do something like this:

```
    // In your Modal

    public function getLeadById($statusId)
    {
        return Lead::where('status', $statusId)->get();
        // you could of course extend this and do something like this:
        // return Lead::where('status', $statusId)->limit()....->get();
    }
```

Basically I am doing a where and returning every lead with a specific id.

You can then use this function in your controller like this:

```
Lead::getLeadById(1)
```

Comment: Not what I'm trying, I expanded the question