# Laravel, whereHas checking latest record of a relationship only

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 2 tables (**posts**, **revisions**), and there is a relationship between them
A **post** has many **revisions** (One to Many relationship)
**Revisions** table has a column called **status** (*approved* or *rejected*)
Now, I want to select all **posts**, if its latest **revision** is *approved*
I tried a lot of methods, but I could get the **posts** that have an *approved* status

---

**Update**

I found a good solution in that reply

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53120558/9500574

Comment: Do you also have timestamps in your revisions table?

Comment: yes, I have timestamps

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53120558/4848587.

Comment: Thanks @JonasStaudenmeir, It works perfectly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - whereHas checking latest record of a relationship without checking others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115064/laravel-wherehas-checking-latest-record-of-a-relationship-without-checking-oth)

Answer (score 2):

```
Post::with([ 'revisions' => function($query) {
   $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where('status', 'approved')->limit(1);   
}])->get()->filter(function($item) {
   return $item->revisions->count() > 0;
});
```

The collection will contain only those posts with approved revisions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Is there any way to filter the results directly during the query, without using the method of **filter** after getting the results

Comment: There is no way without filtering, because Posts always exists, even without revision.