# Laravel, selecting all Posts where its first approved revision is published

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables **Articles** and **Revisions**
There is a relationship between them **one2many**

The **Revisions** table has 2 columns **isApproved** and **isPublished**

Now, I want to select all **articles**, when its first **Approved** revision is **Published**

```
Article::whereHas('revisions', function ($query) {
    $query->where('isApproved', 1)->where('isPublished', 1);
});
```

But this code selected all articles that have approved and published revisions

Answer (score 1):

Try filter the results:

```php
$articles = Article::
               whereHas('revisions', function ($query) {
                   $query->where('isApproved', 1)->where('isPublished', 1);
               })
               ->get()
               ->filter(function ($article) {
                    return $article->revisions->first(function ($revision) {
                               return $revision->isApproved == true;
                           })
                           ->isPublished == true;

               });
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to avoid using Filter method, I'm trying to use the answer in this page, but I failed https://stackoverflow.com/a/53120558/9500574

Comment: I think I got the appropriate solution