# Is there a way to select the last record then filter with relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table named freight, with has many historics, with the table name freight_historic. 1:N. In this historic table i have 3 columns,the `id`(primary key, auto incremented), the `freight_id` and `freight_statuses_id`.

A freight can have multiple historic with status, the last historic row from a specific freight determines your current status.

The freight_statuses table has some columns, ID and NAME. and some records. A small example below

```
+----+-----------+
| ID | NAME      |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | TRAVELING |
+----+-----------+
| 2  | CANCELLED |
+----+-----------+
```

The freight_historics could be

```
+----+------------+---------------------+
| ID | FREIGHT_ID | FREIGHT_STATUSES_ID |
+----+------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 1          | 1                   |
+----+------------+---------------------+
| 2  | 1          |  2                  |
+----+------------+---------------------+  --> last row inserted
```

I tried this code to show all freights with has TRAVELING status, but a freight has 2 historics, with statuses TRAVELING and CANCELLED(WITH THE LAST RECORD INSERTED), still shows me the result.

```
$freight = Freight::with(['lastStatus.statusName'])->whereHas('lastStatus.statusName', function ($query) {
             $query->where('name', 'TRAVELING');
 })->get();


//Models
class FreightHistoric extends Model
{
    public function statusName() {
        return $this->belongsTo(FreightStatus::class, 'freight_statuses_id', 'id');
    }
}


class Freight extends Model
{
     public function lastStatus()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(FreightHistoric::class, 'freight_id', 'id')->latest();
    }
}
```

This code shows all records, with 'TRAVELING` status. I want to show the freight's with' TRAVELING 'status in his historic only if its the last record.

Comment: i think you should use orderby('id', 'desc')

Comment: @samju this will not work

Comment: This requires a more complex query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53120558/4848587

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

```
$latestHistoric= DB::table('freight_historics')
    ->latest()
    ->first();
```

Comment: not like that, I want to get all the last data with status "Cancelled" or "Traveling"

Comment: then change the relationship to hasMany

class Freight extends Model
{
     public function lastStatus()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FreightHistoric::class, 'freight_id', 'id')->latest();
    }
}